# Access selected Items after Postback ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net

First time posting here, so if something doesn't fit, just let me know. Also I'm not very experienced with ASP and C#, so if I just overlooked something obvious, I'm sorry.

The problem:
In the Page_Load, I call my own class MyGridViewExtension. In the constructor of this class, a Gridview will be created. The catch is: In the Headers of this Gridview is not only a Literal, but also a Listbox. The use of these Listboxes is the filtering of the displayed data, which is achieved by marking one (or more, but that doesn't matter) options of the Listbox and then clicking a button for the postback.

I tried to work with the SelectedIndexChanged Event, but that only fires AFTER the Page_Load is already completed, and as my constructor is called in it, after my GridView has already been created.

```
//this is the selectedIndexChanged Event Handler
private void AddToFilterList(Object sender, EventArgs e){
    ListBox source=sender as ListBox;
    string attributeName=source.Parent.ID; //get column name
    List<string> filterList=new List<string>();
    foreach(ListItem singleFilter in Source.Items){
        if(singleFilter.Selected==true){
            filterList.Add(singleFilter.Text);
        }
    }
}
//This works
```

The problem is, that the Constructor will complete before AddToFilterList even gets called, and afterwards it doesn't help anymore, as I need the filterList when in the constructor.

As for other code, it looks somewhat like this:

```
public Class MyGridViewExtension(Array Data){
    checkForSelectedOptions();   //how can I have my filterList here already?
    List<string> columnNames=getAllColumnNamesByCheckingData(Data);
    //-create the template field to show the data
    foreach (string col in columnNames)
    {            
        TemplateField tfield = new TemplateField();           
        //In here, the listboxes are created     
        tfield.HeaderTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Header, col, this);
        tfield.ItemTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Item, col, this);
        this.Columns.Add(tfield);
    }
    this.DataSource=Data; //I actually transform the array to a datatable before, but that shouldn't matter here
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Array data=getDataFromWebserver(); //works
    MyGridViewExtension thisNewGridView=new MyGridViewExtension(data);
    thisNewGridView.DataBind();
    divName.Controls.Add(thisNewGridView); //add the gridview to a div on the page
}
```

Everything works fine, getting data and displaying it, but what blocks me is that I just can't get the selected Items of the Listboxes (the filterList variable) into the Constructor.

EDIT: I should probably add that I should hold the code in the page_load as small as possible, as my job is only the Extension class and every entry in the page_load has to be made (every time) when my class is called, which should be kept to a minimum.

Thanks in advance for potential answers, comments (and edits, as my post probably isn't as good as I hope it to be).
I already edited heavily, because I overlooked something important; sorry for all those who already tried to understand/answer.

LAST EDIT: I somewhat solved the problem by re-enabling ViewState for the entire GridView, which causes some overriding problems. But those were easier to deal with than the problem described here, so that is probably the better route.
Thanks to everybody who gave tips.

Comment: Any reason for creating your own customized `GridView`?

Comment: Adding more filtering, sorting and displaying functions to it, as well as giving it some special variables (for example, being able to tell it that it should let out column number 3 when displaying just by going "my... thisview=new my...(); thisview.columnToHide=3;)
The overall reason is a webtool, and the programmers are sick of creating such functions for each different page/dataset. So a generic class is needed, that has all and everything available.

Comment: What happening is, you created your own `GridView` which is good :). But you are recreating and adding on every `Page_Load`, so the previous `GridView` value what you suppose to have is lost. So you don't get what was there before.

Comment: Instead of creating and adding on `Page_Load`, can you add it as a normal `GridView`? like `<asp:GridView />` tag?

Comment: Yes, but it's necessary to override it on every page_load as I have to apply the filter/sorts/etc. The problem now is that I do not seem to be able to throw a param to the new GridView...unless there is a way to get the filters and create the updatet GridView without using the Page_Load, but I haven't seen that way yet.
To the second comment: No, I cannot access the asp file, only the C# file.

Comment: Instead of filtering after sending data to Grid, can you filter data before and send the filtered list to grid?

Comment: I would need to find a way to get the filters and do some kind of action before calling the postback. Without resorting to JavaScript, (with my little knowledge of ASP), I don't see how I would be able to do that...maybe I'm just blind though.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Array data;
    if (IsPostback)
    {
        data = Session["data"] == null ? getDataFromWebserver() : Session["data"] // if session is null, go get data, otherwise use session variable.
    }
    else
    {
        // Go get you data, since it is a first load or a refresh
        // once you have data - put it in session
        Session["data"] =  getDataFromWebserver(); 
        data = Session["data"];
    } 

    MyGridViewExtension thisNewGridView=new MyGridViewExtension(data);
    thisNewGridView.DataBind();
    divName.Controls.Add(thisNewGridView); //add the gridview to a div on the page

    // No you can do whatever you need to do...
    // some code
}
```

try this, see if it helps.

This works. It loads a dropdown list from which you may select an item, upon which data is filtered. This is what you are describing or at least the way I understand it. Dropdown maybe substituted for your listboxes, however, I think ddl's are cleaner looking (personal preference though).

Code-behind:

```
    using xxx.DB;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    namespace xxx_Internal_SQL.PostTree.Reports.FailedLeads
    {
        public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            private string programName = "Post_Reports_FailedLeads";

            private List<string> lstTransactionSource = new List<string>();
            private List<string> lstTransactionSubSource = new List<string>();
            private List<string> lstTransactionRef = new List<string>();
            private List<string> lstTransactionSubRef = new List<string>();
            private List<string> lstIsTest = new List<string>();

            private string TransactionSource = string.Empty;
            private string TransactionSubSource = string.Empty;
            private string TransactionRef = string.Empty;
            private string TransactionSubRef = string.Empty;
            private string IsTest = string.Empty;

            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (IsPostBack)
                    {
                        if (Session["myDataView"] != null)
                            BindDataToGV((DataView)Session["myDataView"]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        FillDDL();
                        ViewState["sortOrder"] = "";
                        Session["OriginalDT"] = null;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Global.ReportProblem(ex, programName, "Page_Load");
                }
            }

            private void FillTable(string sortExp, string sortDir)
            {
                try
                {
                    ClearGV();

                    object myData;
                    DataTable dtData = GetData();
                    Session["OriginalDT"] = dtData;

                    if (sortExp != string.Empty)
                    {
                        DataView myDataView = new DataView();
                        myDataView = dtData.AsDataView();

                        myDataView.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", sortExp, sortDir);

                        dtData = myDataView.ToTable();
                        Session["OriginalDT"] = dtData;
                        Session["myDataView"] = myDataView;

                        myData = myDataView;
                    }
                    BindDataToGV(dtData);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Global.ReportProblem(ex, programName, "FillTable");
                }
            }

            private DataTable GetData()
            {
                return GetData(db, values);
            }
            private void ClearGV()
            {
                gvTransactions.DataSource = null;
                gvTransactions.DataBind();
            }
            private void BindDataToGV(object obj)
            {

                gvTransactions.DataSource = obj;
                gvTransactions.DataBind();
            }
            private DataTable GetData(Database db, SortedList<string, string> values)
            {
                DataTable dt = null;

                try
                {
                    if (db.GenericSP("sp_xxx", values, true))
                        return db.Output_DT;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Global.ReportProblem(ex, programName, "GetData");
                }

                return dt;
            }
            protected void lnkFindTransactions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (ddlAffiliates.SelectedIndex > 0) FillTable("", "");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Global.ReportProblem(ex, programName, "lnkFindTransactions_Click");
                }
            }
            protected void gvTransactions_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
            {
                FillTable(e.SortExpression, sortOrder);
            }
            protected void gvTransactions_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
            {
                gvTransactions.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

                if (Session["OriginalDT"] != null)
                    BindDataToGV((DataTable)Session["OriginalDT"]);
            }
            public string sortOrder
            {
                get
                {
                    if (ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString() == "desc")
                    {
                        ViewState["sortOrder"] = "asc";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewState["sortOrder"] = "desc";
                    }

                    return ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString();
                }
                set
                {
                    ViewState["sortOrder"] = value;
                }
            }
            private void FillDDL()
            {
                if (db.GetRecords("sp_xxx"))
                {
                    DataTable dt = db.Output_DT;

                    ddlAffiliates.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select...", ""));
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                        ddlAffiliates.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr["name"].ToString(), dr["aid"].ToString()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

front-end:

```
        <asp:Table runat="server">
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell Width="100px" HorizontalAlign="Right">Date: </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell Width="200px" HorizontalAlign="Left">
                    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender runat="server" Animated="true"
                        ID="extCalendarEnd" TargetControlID="txtDateEnd">
                    </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateEnd" runat="server" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell Width="75px" HorizontalAlign="Left">Seller: </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell Width="200px" HorizontalAlign="Left">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAffiliates" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:DropDownList>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Left">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" ID="upnlFind" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFindTransactions" runat="server" CssClass="linkButton" OnClick="lnkFindTransactions_Click" Text="Find" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="5">
                    <hr />
                    <asp:Panel runat="server" Width="600px" Height="100%">
                        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlGridview" Width="500px" Style="margin: 0px auto 0px auto;">
                            <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvTransactions"
                                GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True"
                                AllowSorting="True" PageSize="25"
                                CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"
                                Width="600px" OnSorting="gvTransactions_Sorting"
                                OnPageIndexChanging="gvTransactions_PageIndexChanging"
                                RowStyle-Wrap="false" CssClass="gvTransactions">
                                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                                <PagerSettings Position="TopAndBottom" Mode="NumericFirstLast" />
                                <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                                <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
```

as a closing note. It is not a perfect all addressing code, but it does what it was designed to do. Feel free to build on-top of it or modify any part of it.

Comment: Sorry, but this let's the complete gridview vanish, as I postback quite often and do not have viewstate set. Though I will have to change the question a bit, as I have changed something in my code and now there is another problem. Sorry for taking up your time.

Comment: as much as I understand, you should get your data, put a copy of it in session, then do your work. for each postback, you should reload it from session and then call your events.

Comment: I changed the question now, because I heavily misunderstood something myself. As the problem is that I need my events to fire before my Page_load completes (which in itself isn't possible as far as I know), your answer will probably not help, though there is still the possibility that I misunderstand something else.

Comment: since each postback represents an instance of the page in the past, then you MUST recreate it on a postback before any events are called. Therefore, on postback, first thing to do is to recreate your gridview. Then your "OnIndexChanged" will start magically work. otherwise, controls are just not there...

Comment: I find it pretty counter-intuitive that, when I create the Listboxes after the postback, the OnIndexChanged with the selected items from BEFORE the postback is called...but I see your point, and that's why I need another way to get the filterList before the constructor finishes.

Comment: think of it as a cake shop. Once a baker have a cake done and gives it away, then he has no retained copy of that cake. If a consumer wants something to do to that cake, then the baker need to recreate that cake first, and then make any alterations to that cake. You cannot have something which you already consumed. In our case it is a page which you sent to a client.

Comment: If we stick to the cake example...the baker creates and sells the cake. Then, when he bakes the second cake, how does he know which parts of the first cake the consumer touched (as an example)? Thats the part that I have problems with understanding...because if I recreate the listboxes, I should not be able to know which were clicked and which not.

Comment: Ahha! good point! and at that point the consumer (postback) comes in and says, take that little thingy off, and add that huge thing... and make it more sweet, and by the way, add some sour cream... So essentially, baker(server) knows that he needs to make a cake and consumer(postback from client) tells him what modifications to do.

Comment: after that, baker(server) sends(postback) that cake back to a consumer (modified per request page)

Comment: I see, very good image...but to the original question, how would I pack these infos into the postback from the client? I feel like that's so easy that I should know it, but somehow I don't get it.

Comment: it is being handled for you. check the answer, I will update it in a sec

Comment: Tried around with sessions and your code, but the original problem still exists, as I can't write into the session which Items have been selected, as the SelectedIndexChanged triggers after the Page_Load. Even when I replace Page_Load with Page_PreRender, there is no way for me to getting to the orinial ListBoxes. The only idea I have left at this point is dumping all selected Items into a hidden, in the ASP file created Input or the like and then using that...but that would be quite a dirty solution. Might be that I'm just as dense as a brick wall, but somehow I don't see how it should work.

Comment: what sort of filters do you use?

Comment: All the filters in the ListBoxes are just simple strings.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for putting so much time into this. In the end, I didn't end up using your solution, but reenabled the viewstate on my gridview (which was originally causing problems, which I fixed by creating this very problem here...99 little bugs in the code etc.), and then overwriting the whole table with the Button_OnClick Handler. Nevertheless, I learned a lot from your suggestions. As this is my first question: Should I accept your answer, even though I didn't use it in the end, or just let this post like it is?

Comment: well, technically you did not use the solution I have provided, so I would not accept it. I would vote it up, as long as you found it useful, but that is entirely up to you. I usually provide some info for the benefit of the person who is asking and not to collect point :)

Comment: Ok, I would definitly upvote it, but as I currently not have enough reputation to do so, I'll just let it at this state. If I ever get enough, I'll remember you and come back to it^^ Thanks again for all the help and time you provided, it was very much appreciated.